# how to filter a JavaRDD using a List using java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaRDD with some json documents, I want to filter the JavaRDD based on a list of ID's in a ArrayList, basically want to get all the documents in the JavaRDD which has the ID which is in the ArrayList. I know this can be done easily on DataSet but not sure how to do it with JavaRDD

Comment: How do you represent the JSON in the RDD, and how do you access the ID you're referring to? Generally, JavaRDD has a `filter()` method, taking a function parameter operating on a row in your RDD (thus my question what exactly do you store in each row, i.e., how the JSON is represented there), and returning a boolean. I can probably give you a code snippet in the answer once you give me more info

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give the example the  json document like this [
  {
    "$1": {
      "cas": 1513356396096127000,
      "flags": 33554432,
      "id": "CD1e23456782",
      "type": "json"
    }
  }
] and the arrayList is ["CD1e23456782","CDde23456782"] like this, I can get the json document by id

Comment: Sorry, still not quite clear to me. What's `$1`? Does each of the JSON documents has `$1` property, or is it different from one to another? Or is it just the RDD representation, and the actual JSON is just `{ "cas": 1513356396096127000, "flags": 33554432, "id": "CD1e23456782", "type": "json" }`? Also, is the JSON stored as String in RDD, or as some sort of object structure? BTW you can edit your original question to add information, instead of commenting, makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javaRdd.filter(json -> arrayList.contains(json.get("id")))
```

That's a high-level snippet, with `json` being what's stored in each row of your RDD (I'm not sure what kind of structure is there and how JSON is represented), `arrayList` is your list of IDs, and `json.get("id")` just denotes *some* way of obtaining the ID from your JSON - again, without more info it's hard to be more specific

Comment: Alex, do you know how to get all the json documents that are are not in the arraylist to a new RDD

Comment: To get a list of documents that are **not** in the arraylist, you simply reverse the filter condition: `javaRdd.filter(json -> !arrayList.contains(json.get("id")))`